# Can I add more triggers?

Tags: shell, unix

Here is a script below that will trigger on particular time by logical OR gate 00.01 and 00.07 and 00.13 mean to say

This below script trigger at 00.01 or 00.07 or 00.13 Can I add more time is it will work fine?

below is script now working fine :-

```
if [ $MCURR_DATE1 -eq "0001" ] || [ $MCURR_DATE1 -eq "0007" ] || [ $MCURR_DATE1 -eq "0013" ] ;
 then
```

Can I add three more trigger times like below update (I want to add three more trigger times 00.16, 00.19, 00.22):

```
if [ $MCURR_DATE1 -eq "0001" ] || [ $MCURR_DATE1 -eq "0007" ] || [ $MCURR_DATE1 -eq "0013" ] ||
   [ $MCURR_DATE1 -eq "0016" ] || [ $MCURR_DATE1 -eq "0019" ] || [ $MCURR_DATE1 -eq "0022" ];
then
```

Does it work?

Comment: We have no idea what data is contained in that `$MCURR_DATE1`, since you do not write where that variable comes from. So the answer probably is: _if_ that variable contains the strings you compare against then yes, the conditional will act as expected or desired. But it completely depends on what data you have in that variable.

Comment: Dear arascha i already defined that variable MCURR_DATE1 = 'date + "%H%M" and working fine but i need to dd 3 more triiggers timing 0016,0019,0022 . can it work?

Comment: Short answer: yes.  But maybe you want to tell us why you ask this here instead of just testing it yourself.  I have the feeling that testing it would be easier than asking ;-)

Comment: this vriable contain current date.

Comment: I'm sure you can test with _faked_ values by just inserting a line of code like `MCURR_DATE1=0016` to test the or-expression.

Answer (score 0):

While what you posted works, it's somewhat lengthy. Consider instead:

```
case $MCURR_DATE1 in 0001|0007|0013|0016|0019|0022)
    # this equates to the if-then block
esac    # like fi
```

If you need an `else`, insert

```
    ;;
*)  # this equates to the 'else' block
```

before the `esac` line.